# Fitting the contents of a matrix with TikZ's fit option

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, fit

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \matrix{
      \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
%      \\
%   };
   \node[draw=red, fit={(0,0) (1,1)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A square with a red fit]

If the three commented lines are now uncommented, and the command `pdflatex test` is rerun, a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: A fitted square inside a matrix]

Why does the introduction of the matrix change the position of the red square relative to the black one? How can I predict and determine where the red square be drawn relative to the matrix' contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because things in a matrix node are essentially placed inside a new `tikzpicture` environment (not exactly, but it is easier to understand it this way, I think) and hence the coordinate system within a matrix node does not match the system outside.

You might notice that the center of the black square sits at the "global coordinate" `(0,0)` (that is, relative to the coordinate system outside the matrix). This is because you did not specify any coordinate for the matrix which makes it default to `(0,0)` as its anchor, and since the matrix only contains one single matrix node, the center of this matrix node is also aligned at this coordinate. This explains why the black square sits at this position in the diagram and tells us that its coordinates in the system outside the matix are `(-0.5,-0.5)` and `(0.5,0.5)` in this case.

If you want to `fit` something around things that are inside a matrix node, you need to either place the `fit` macro inside this matrix node as well or you need to name the relevant coordinates on order to be able to refer to them later.

You can also name the whole matrix of course, which may be helpful depending on what exactly you want to `fit`. Note, however, that a matrix creates some padding around its child nodes by default.

The following code snippet might help you to get an idea about what is going on and how things are placed:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   
    % naming the matrix as `m` for later reference
    \matrix (m) {
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        % using `fit` inside the matrix node
        \node[draw=yellow, fit={(0,0) (1,1)}] {};
        
        % defining coordinates inside the matrix node for later reference
        \coordinate (zero-zero inside matrix) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (one-one inside matrix) at (1,1);
        \\
    };
    
    % marking coordinate (0,0) outside of matrix
    \fill[blue] (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
    % drawing the rectangle that the following `fit` command refers to
    \draw[lightgray] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \node[draw=red, fit={(0,0) (1,1)}] {};
    
    % drawing a `fit` around the whole matrix: note the padding
    \node[draw=green, fit={(m)}] {};
    
    % drawing a `fit` around the coordinates inside the matrix node
    \node[draw=blue, dashed, fit={(zero-zero inside matrix) (one-one inside matrix)}] {};
    
    % drawing a square that matches the coordinates of the square inside the matrix node
    \draw[orange, dashed] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case that the question is "how to draw a border around a matrix", a possible solution is to `draw` the `matrix border`. A `matrix` is a `node` who contains `cells`. And all options for `nodes` can be applyed to the `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix [draw=red]{
      \draw[black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
      \\
   };
%   \node[draw=red, fit={(0,0) (1,1)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]