# How to scale tikz pictures that include matrices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, scale

The following LaTeX document is saved in a file whose path is `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
   \tikz[transform shape, scale=1.0] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \tikz[transform shape, scale=0.5] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \tikz[transform shape, scale=1.0] \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};
   \tikz[transform shape, scale=0.5] \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};
\end{document}
```

When the following commands are executed at the terminal:

> cd ~
> pdflatex test

a PDF file is generated at the path `~/test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows:

[image: Scaled squares]

The scaling had no effect on those TikZ pictures with matrices. Why? How can I scale TikZ pictures that include matrices?

Comment: Because, as stated in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664700/47927), inside a matrix, there is essetially another `tikzpicture` environment unrelated to the outer coordinate system. You only scale the outer environment and its coordinate system, but not the one inside the matrix. You can do `\tikz \matrix{\draw[scale=0.5] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};`.

Comment: The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) states in section that "Rotations and scaling have no effect on a matrix as a whole (however, you can still transform the contents of the cells normally). Before the matrix is typeset, the rotational and scaling part of the transformation matrix is reset."

Comment: @JasperHabicht This is not a good solution. If I want to scale an entire tikzpicture, having to manually scale individual components within it feels wrong, inefficient, and error-prone, as well as having to remember which components scale automatically and which ones require manual intervention.

Comment: It was rather an explanation than a solution. I don't know what you want to achieve, but you could try to scale all matrix cells using `\tikz[every matrix/.style={cells={scale=0.5}}] \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht This is a slightly better solution.

Comment: If you tell me a bit more about your exact set up, I could maybe come up with a nicer one. Note that scaling a `tikzpicture` always only scales the coordinate system. I think you are after something similar to `transform shape`. Sadly, this has no effect here. You can always place the `tikzpicture` inside a box and scale this box, which, however will also decrease the line widths.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, I was after something similar to `transform shape`, which is why I used `transform shape` in my minimal working example. It is indeed sad that it has no effect on matrices.

Comment: Well, you could create your own super-transform style which would maybe something like `transform everything/.style={transform shape, #1, every matrix/.style={cells={#1}}}` and then use `transform everything={scale=0.5}` ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Sounds good. Could you add it to your answer, please? Where do I create this super-transform? Inside a `tikzset` environment in the preamble?

Comment: There is also `transform canvas`. It really depends on your concrete use case, I fear.

Comment: @JasperHabicht What's the difference between `transform canvas` and the `transform everything` option that you've created?

Comment: `transform canvas` will also scale line widhts. If you are fine with this, this might be the way to go ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Ti*k*Z/PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) states that "Rotations and scaling have no effect on a matrix as a whole (however, you can still transform the contents of the cells normally). Before the matrix is typeset, the rotational and scaling part of the transformation matrix is reset."

Using `\tikz[scale=0.5] \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};` you therefore scale the outer coordinate system in which the outer matrix node sits, but not the coordinate system within the matrix cells. You can, however, scale the cells using `every matrix/.style={cells={scale=0.5}}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
   \tikz[scale=1.0] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
   \tikz[scale=0.5] \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);

   \tikz \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};
   \tikz[every matrix/.style={cells={scale=0.5}}] \matrix{\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);\\};
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I guess, you are after some option line `transform shape` that also applies to matrices. You could try `transform canvas` which, however, would also transform the line widths. You also could create your own transformation option that also includes the above cell transformation (place this inside your preamble or somewhere after `tikz` has been loaded and before the first use of the defined option):

```
\tikzset{
    transform everything/.style={transform shape, #1, every matrix/.style={cells={#1}}}
}
```

Then use `transform everything={scale=0.5}` as option to your `tikzpicture` or `\tikz` command. I did not test this extensively, however, so handle with care. In certain cases, the outcome may be not as intended due to the doubled application of the transformations. Also, while this could work with `scale`, other transformations such as `rotate` won't work well, I guess.